# 2008 Honda Accord Automatic Transmission - Transmission seems to be slipping. Is it serious?

Tags: honda, automatic-transmission, accord

I have a 2008 Honda Accord with an automatic transmission. I don't know much about cars. The car seems to be having problems switching gears, especially in low gear. For example, often when I'm accelerating from a stop, things will go fine at first and then once I've gained a little bit of speed the engine will seem to rev for a while before switching into the next gear. Sometimes taking my foot off the accelerator will help it along, but this doesn't always work, either. It's possible the transmission is slipping into neutral, but I think power is still going to the engine, even when it's rev-ing. The transmission doesn't seem to have the problem at higher speeds.

I've already had it checked out by a mechanic and they recommended I repair the transmission, which would cost $4K. They didn't seem too sure about it though and it makes me think the problem may not be so serious.

What do others think? Is this a serious problem? Is there anything I can do to work around it without actually needing to repair the transmission?

Comment: Have you checked the transmission fluid? Is there enough in it? Does it smell burnt? How many miles on the vehicle? Have you ever had a transmission service done?

Comment: $4K and they are not sure?!? Run away from that place and find a reputable mechanic. No workarounds, though. You will have to get some work done to it. The more time passes the more expensive it might get.

Comment: Rather than slipping, is it just staying in a low gear too long, so the engine is revving too much?

Comment: I had the transmission fluid replaced and the problem remained. 106K miles on the car. Never had transmission serviced before. The place where I had the car checked ($4K and seemingly not so sure place) was a dealership. About slipping or just staying in low gear... I think it's just staying in low gear. Or, it's possibly slipping into neutral in low gear and then finally popping into the higher gear. It only happens between low gears and it seems to happen even when I manually switch gears using the lower drive gears under D. Are there any tests I can perform to better diagnose the issue?

Comment: Have you checked to the fluid levels for your Automatic Transmission Fluid?